# How to disable "sync" pane in "build" tab keep popping up in IntellijIdea

Tags: intellij-idea

Every time I change branch, which includes pom.xml change, and project is re-imported (either manually or automatically) I get pop up notifying me about successful result of sync. How to turn it off?

Why I don't want this: I have to do this action very often. I kinda know, that this import will be successful 99.9999% of times. And in principle I'm totally not interested, that action, which I suspect it to be successful, or which should be successful every time, was actually successful. Moreover I never saw there sync failure even if it actually failed. So this "tool" is just time-wasting distraction. How to turn it off?

Comment: Please vote for this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215613

Answer (score -1):

You can navigate to `Preferences | Appearance and Behavior | Notifications` and manage your notifications. You can disable all balloon notifications if that annoys you or select a specific group of notification. Refer to this [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-notifications.html)

Probably the most appropriate notification for your case is `Maven import`.

Comment: that does not help. I disabled all popups. Changed branch way to the past. No maven popup about importing as expected. So I clicked import manually. "Build" toolbar got opened, with "sync" pane notifying me about success. This is what I want to disable. I don't want to be notified about success, I want to be notified about failure. Just like in car. I don't want: lambda probe ok, click confirm for next. Tyre pressure ok, click confirm for next. Oil OK, click ...